# win32 folder not found after "easy_install pywin32"

Tags: winapi, python-2.7, virtualenv

ImportError: No module named win32api this is the error i am getting. and looking at other posts i know that pywin32 is what missing from my virtualenv.

i tried easy_install pywin32.. but it didnt install the "win32" folder and win32api is part if win32 and i still get importError error.

i dont want to isntall the .exe (pywin32-219.win32-py2.7 fixes) which as mentioned in other posts since i will be making changes to the source and running it though automation hooks.

i am using python 2.7.6 version

Comment: Maybe you've already seen it, but [a related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8078216/1810429) and answers to it may help.

Comment: I tried it but that didnt help

Comment: I am getting the below error when i followed the steps mentioned

Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe/download
Processing download
error: Couldn't find a setup script in c:\users\c_skatha\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-5ept50\download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy_install "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build 219/pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. I'm using portable python 2.7 on windows 7 machine